# How would I create a method that returns the second letter of a string?

Tags: javascript, methods, charat

Examples:

- `secondLetter("bob")` should return an 'o'.
- `secondLetter("yummy")` should return an 'u'.

I tried using `charAt`, but I didn't understand how to format it.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @Zandew I think, it is very likely javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like the following:

```
let secondLetter = word => return word[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` is a method of all string variables. Thus, you should call it like `myString.charAt(x)`. Here `x` is the count of the character in the string, starting by 0.

Thus, to get the second character, you need to call `myString.charAt(1)`.

The function which generates it is this:

```
function secondLetter(str) {
  return str.charAt(1);
}
```

To make it to a method (which is essentially a function, bound to an object), you need to put thus function into the object prototype.